Use chroma (database) local on c#
I want to use chroma in a c# project.
I alredy did a python project that stores chroma data local using chromadb.persistenClient. I don't want my data to be stored in an online server but rather local.
I tried using multiple forms of Microsofts ChromaClient class which seems to the the only way to use chroma on c# and requires a chroma server endpoint url

Please post your code.  It tends to be rather difficult to spot issues and problems without it!

Mind that the example connects to an endpoint on the local machine : const string endpoint = "http://localhost:8000"; => https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/tree/main/dotnet/src/Connectors/Connectors.Memory.Chroma , I would guess "PersistentClient" does the same under the hood, but I haven't checked.
